# How can we trigger multiple jobs in AWS glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I'm new to AWS glue, can anyone please explain how we can triggers multiple jobs together through a single jobs or through any other means.

Comment: If your can provide some useful links that would be helpful

Comment: AWS Glue just released a new Workflow piece that may be exactly what you are looking for. CHeck out the documentation : [AWS Glue : Workflows](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/aws-glue-now-provides-workflows-to-orchestrate-etl-workloads/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Lambda function  .
In Lambda code import boto3

build a dictionary with all the gluejobnames . Then loop on it and pass the gluejobname one by one to trigger all the glue jobs you want to trigger  .

```
 import boto3
 client = boto3.client('glue')
 response = client.start_job_run(
   JobName=glueJobName.get(gluejobname),
   Arguments={
     '--day_partition_key': 'date',
     '--hour_partition_key': 'hour'
   }
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Glue workflow, Glue triggers will help you -

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/trigger-job.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/workflows_overview.html